# How to check if a function is available in instantiated controller for unit testing in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unittest a controller in AngularJS for the first time. I want to test if the login-function in this controller calls the right service but I get the error, that the function doesn't exist in the controller. What did I do wrong? Do I have to mock more? But I shouldn't have to mock the functions in the controller to be tested because if I would do that the whole testing would be senseless, or am I wrong?

Controller-Snippet:

```
function LoginController($scope, $state, myService, ngToast) {

    $scope.loginUser = loginUser;

    activate();
    function activate() {}

    function loginUser(credentials) {
       myService.authenticate(/*things*/);
    }
}
```

Test-Code:

```
describe('Login Controller', function () {
'use strict';

//globals
var controller, scope;
var $controller, $state, myService, ngToast;

//needed modules
beforeEach(module('app.login'));
beforeEach(module('app.core'));    
beforeEach(module('ui.router'));

//instanciate Controller        
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$state_, _myService_,  _ngToast_) {
    scope = {};
    $state = _$state_;
    myService = _myService_;
    ngToast = _ngToast_;

    $controller = _$controller_;

    controller = $controller('LoginCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        $state: $state,
        myService: myService,
        ngToast: ngToast
    });
}));

it('should have an existing controller', function () {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
});

/*************************** unit-tests ***************************/
describe('.loginUser()', function () {
    it('should exist', function () {
        expect(controller.loginUser).toBeDefined();
    });
});
});
```

The Error I am getting when running karma start:

```
.loginUser()
  ✗ should exist
TypeError: controller.loginUser is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (src/login/login.controller.spec.js:74:31)
```

But it seems to me that the controller does exist, because this test doesn't fail:

```
Login Controller
 ✓ should have an existing controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because loginUser is defined on $scope and not on the controller so loginUser is not bound to your controller object in your test.

To test loginUser please do the following:

- Inject $rootScope in your beforeEach
- Set scope = $rootScope.$new()
- The controller should be created with this scope
- Your test should check if loginUser is defined on the scope

  ```
      describe('Login Controller', function () {
       'use strict';

       //globals
       var controller, scope;
      var $controller, $state, myService, ngToast;

      //needed modules
      beforeEach(module('app.login'));
      beforeEach(module('app.core'));    
      beforeEach(module('ui.router'));

      //instanciate Controller        
      beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$state_, _myService_,  _ngToast_, _$rootScope_) {
           scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
           $state = _$state_;
           myService = _myService_;
           ngToast = _ngToast_;

           $controller = _$controller_;

           controller = $controller('LoginCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            $state: $state,
            myService: myService,
            ngToast: ngToast
           });
         }));

      it('should have an existing controller', function () {
           expect(controller).toBeDefined();
         });

       /*************************** unit-tests ***************************/
       describe('.loginUser()', function () {
          it('should exist', function () {
             expect(scope.loginUser).toBeDefined();
      });
  });
  });
  ```

If you want to test loginUser on the controller itself then make use of the controller as syntax where you would set this.loginUser = loginUser instead of $scope.loginUser = loginUser. Then you will be able to use controller.loginUser in your test.

Comment: thanks a lot! Now it works and I understood angular and testing better!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help. Please mark it as an answer:)